# Sum all numbers converting all negative numbers into positive numbers

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a column of numbers and would like to know the total after everybody has paid me back, but I have negative numbers currently in there:

[image: column example]

So the total of this should be `95`, currently if I do a sum it will be `75`.

This is what I currently have:

```
=SUM(IF(B2:B27<0,-1*B2:B27,B2:B27))
```

but this doesn't work of course as it does it on the total of all the rows within the range in the column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
=ArrayFormula(sum(abs(B2:B27)))
```

[ABS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093459)

(For an answer of `105` if all the numbers displayed fall into the range (and no others).)

Comment: Wowza sir... You have skills with sheets :)